# Почему в списке под android картинки разного размера?

Tags: android

layout для 1 item для adaptor выводяться картинки разного размера, как такое возможно?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:weightSum="100">
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_weight="85"
        android:layout_marginRight="4dp">
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv0"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Загадка 1"
        android:layout_marginTop="6dp"
        android:lines="1"

        android:textSize="24sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:textColor="#060606"/>
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/label_title"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Описание загадки"
        android:layout_marginTop="6dp"
        android:textColor="#060606"
        android:lines="1">
    </TextView>
    </LinearLayout>
<ImageView
    android:layout_width="32dp"
    android:layout_height="32dp"
    android:src="@drawable/check"
    android:layout_weight="20"
    android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
    android:id="@+id/imageView"
    android:layout_marginTop="6dp"
    android:layout_gravity="center"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Намудрил, вот так верно:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:weightSum="100">
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:weightSum="100"
     >
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv0"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Загадка 1"
        android:layout_marginTop="6dp"
        android:lines="1"
        android:textSize="24sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:textColor="#060606"
        android:layout_weight="90"/>
        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="32dp"
            android:layout_height="32dp"
            android:src="@drawable/check"
            android:layout_weight="10"
            android:id="@+id/imageView"/>


    </LinearLayout>
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/label_title"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Описание загадки"
        android:layout_marginTop="6dp"
        android:textColor="#060606"
        android:lines="1">
    </TextView>
</LinearLayout>
```